# How do I get rid of duplication in ruby when using clone?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

This method is just changing the id for any player_id that is found.  Reek hates it, but I can't find a way to refactor it in a meaningful way.

```
(1..9).each { |n|
    n = n.to_s
    self.player_ids[n] = self.site_id.clone << "_" << self.player_ids[n].clone if self.player_ids[n]        
}
```

Do I just have to live with this duplication because the clone function doesn't allow me to:

```
player_id = self.player_ids[n]
player_id = self.site_id.clone << "_" << player_id.clone if player_id
```

Sample input:

```
{:player_ids => {"2" => "player_name1", "6" => "player_name4", "9" => "player_name9"}
```

output:

```
{:player_ids => {"2" => "PRE_player_name1", "6" => "PRE_player_name4", "9" => "PRE_player_name9"}
```

Comment: Can you try `self.site_id + "_" + self.player_ids[n] if self.player_ids[n] `?

Comment: This cloning and in-place stuff looks pretty bad. Are you sure you want this? why don't you show us one (or more) pair input/desired_output so we can figure out what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I should make a habit of showing the input and output.

Comment: Are you sure you want `player_ids` as a key within a hash rather than being **assigned** to a hash? Your example does not tell that it is itself a hash, so `player_ids[n]` does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible techniques, based on your sample input and output:

```
site_id = 'PRE'
prefix  = "#{site_id}_"
h = {:player_ids => {"2" => "player_name1", "6" => "player_name4", "9" => "player_name9"}}

# If mutating the original hash is not OK
h2 = h.dup
h2[:player_ids] = Hash[ h[:player_ids].map{ |s,n| [s, n.sub(/^/,prefix)] } ]
p h, h2
#=> {:player_ids=>{"2"=>"player_name1", "6"=>"player_name4", "9"=>"player_name9"}}
#=> {:player_ids=>{"2"=>"PRE_player_name1", "6"=>"PRE_player_name4", "9"=>"PRE_player_name9"}}

# If mutating the original hash is OK
h[:player_ids].each{ |id_string,name| name.sub! /^/, prefix }
p h
#=> {:player_ids=>{"2"=>"PRE_player_name1", "6"=>"PRE_player_name4", "9"=>"PRE_player_name9"}}
```

If this is not what you want, please edit your question's sample input/output and post a comment clarifying your needs.

Comment: Thank you!  If site_id = "PRE", is there a better way to append it in the sub than site_id.clone << "_"?  Metrical seems to hate my frequent use of clone.

Comment: @JeremySmith I've edited the answer to include `site_id` as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`#clone` is only required because you are using mutating operations (`<<`) on the string. Using string interpolation prevents the unnecessary clone and also makes your code more idiomatic.

```
player_ids[n] &&= "#{site_id.clone}_#{player_ids[n]}"
```

As a bonus, I've removed your unnecessary references to `self` and replaced your if with an and-equals.